# Chrome Extension: Inject code If the referrer is facebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to inject a code a code into a page if the referrer is facebook but it is not working. This is the code I used below.

**Manifest.json**

```js
{
  "name": "Injecta",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
  "homepage_url": "http://danharper.me",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

I think the problem is here. I want to Inject the code if the url referrer is facebook.

**Background.js**

```js
var x = document.referrer;
if (x === "www.facebook.com" ) {

// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
 // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
  file: 'inject.js'
 });
});
}
```

**Inject.js**

```js
// this is the code which will be injected into a given page...

(function() {

 // just place a div at top right
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.style.position = 'fixed';
 div.style.top = 0;
 div.style.right = 0;
 div.textContent = 'Injected!';
 document.body.appendChild(div);

 alert('inserted self... giggity');

})();
```

I will be glad if you could provide the working code for me.

Comment: Required reading: [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). The background page has no direct access to a webpage. You'll probably have to use webRequest API to check the response headers, see the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There's two bits to your requirement:

1. Checking if the referrer is Facebook (FB),
2. Injecting a script if the referrer is FB.

The first needs to happen in the browser page via an injected content script, since the context of the page (i.e. referrer) is not available directly to the background script.

You could inject a simple referrer detector content script in all pages. When referrer=FB is detected, send a message to background script, which then injects the FB-only script.

Alternatively, you could inject the full script in all pages, but hide the active bits (your inject.js code) behind a test for referrer === FB.

Either way, the detection for referrer needs to happen in the injected content script.

I could help with code, if you want, but I feel it's quite simple. A matter, more of architecture, than code, as @wOxxOm pointed out.

**Update 2016-11-08:**

Re-read your code, and it seems what you intend to do is to inject a script on a page when

1. Referrer is facebook, and
2. User has pressed browser action asking for injection.

Have provided code below for such a scenario.

1. Inject a basic script into all pages, usually done by listing it in the manifest.
2. When browser action is pressed, send a message to the always-injected script asking it if the tab's referrer is facebook.
3. The script responds with `true` if the referrer is facebook -> inject the main script now.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Adding code:

// Updated Manifest - Added content script that's always injected

```
{
  "name": "Injecta",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
  "homepage_url": "http://danharper.me",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["js/inject_all_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

// background.js

```
// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  // send a message to the 'always-injected' script to ask if the page referrer is facebook
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"type": "isFacebook?"}, function(response){
    if(response.answer){
      // if the referrer is facebook, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

// inject_all_script.js

```
// this is the code which will be injected into *all* pages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(sender.id === chrome.runtime.id && message.type && message.type === "isFacebook?"){
    sendResponse({"answer": /https?\/\/(www)?\.facebook\.com/i.test(document.referrer)});
  }
})
```

// selectively-injected.js

```
// this is the code which will be injected into pages that have facebook as referrer...
(function() {

  // just place a div at top right
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.position = 'fixed';
  div.style.top = 0;
  div.style.right = 0;
  div.textContent = 'Injected!';
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  alert('inserted self... giggity');

})();
```

Comment: @seyioluwasade Added code sample. Apologies for the 2 day delay.